# Find the time taken by the man to reach his office given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Walking from Home at $3$/$4$ th of this usual speed, a man reaches his office $20$ minutes late.Had the person walked at $4$/$3$ of his usual speed,find the time taken by the man to reach his office.

options: a)$45$min b)$90$min c)$70$min d)$100$min

My Approach:

I approached this problem using a simple formula taught by my sir to solve these types of problems:

Distance=$3$/$4$ . $4$/$3$($20$+q) / ($4$/$3$ - $3$/$4$)=$12$/$7$ . ($20$+q)

I am getting no Ans towards this problem.Can Anyone give me the hint Why or any other approach that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Walking at $\frac34$ of his usual speed he will need $\frac43$ of the time that is usually needed to reach his office.

So denoting the time usually needed with $t$ we find that $$\frac43t=t+20\text{minutes}$$

Walking at $\frac43$ of his usual speed he will need $\frac34$ of the time that is usually needed to reach his office.